# AWS Lambda function unable to send custom event to newrelic API

Tags: python, python-3.x, aws-lambda, lambda, newrelic

I have a task to create a lambda function to monitor VPC subnets to alert when the number of free IPs is getting to 20. I have created below lambda function but it is unable to make a connection to the newrelic events API

```
`import boto3
import os
import json
import urllib.request

def get_available_ip_count(subnet_info):
return int(subnet_info\['AvailableIpAddressCount'\])

def get_new_relic_api_key(secret_name):
client = boto3.client('secretsmanager')
response = client.get_secret_value(SecretId=secret_name)
secret_data = json.loads(response\['SecretString'\])
return secret_data\['NEW_RELIC_API_KEY'\]

def send_newrelic_alert_event(alert_message, available_ips, api_key):
url = "https://insights-collector.newrelic.com/v1/newrelic_account_name/newrelic_account_id/events"\`

    headers = {
        "X-Insert-Key": api_key,
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
    
    payload = [
        {
            "eventType": "SubnetAlert",
            "alertMessage": alert_message
        }
    ]
    payload_bytes = json.dumps(payload).encode('utf-8')
    req = urllib.request.Request(url, data=payload_bytes, headers=headers, method='POST')
    
    
    try:
        print("Sending request to New Relic:")
        print("req:",req.data)
        print("URL:", req.full_url)
        print("Method:", req.get_method())
        print("Headers:", req.headers)
        print("Payload:", payload)
        with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response:
            if response.status == 200:
                return True
            else:
                return False
    except Exception as e:
        return False

def lambda_handler(event, context):
print("Received event:", json.dumps(event))
ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2')
vpcs_response = ec2_client.describe_vpcs()
vpc_ids = \[vpc\['VpcId'\] for vpc in vpcs_response\['Vpcs'\]\]
print("VPC IDs:", vpc_ids)

    secret_name = "aws_secret/newrelicapikey"
    api_key = get_new_relic_api_key("aws_secret/newrelicapikey")
    
    try:
        alerts = []
        for vpc_id in vpc_ids:
            subnets_info = ec2_client.describe_subnets(Filters=[{'Name': 'vpc-id', 'Values': [vpc_id]}])
            
    
            for subnet_info in subnets_info['Subnets']:
                available_ips = get_available_ip_count(subnet_info)
                print(f"Subnet ID: {subnet_info['SubnetId']}, Available IPs: {available_ips}")
                if available_ips is not None and available_ips < 20:
                    subnet_id = subnet_info['SubnetId']
                    alert_message = f"Subnet {subnet_id} has {available_ips} available IP addresses. Details: {subnet_info}"
                    alerts.append(alert_message)
                    print("Sending New Relic alert...")
                    send_newrelic_alert_event(alert_message, available_ips, api_key)
    
        return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': alerts
        }
    
    except Exception as e:
        return {
            'statusCode': 500,
            'body': str(e)
        }`
```

Output:
`

```
req: b'\[{"eventType": "SubnetAlert", "alertMessage": "SubnetAlert"}\]'
URL: https://insights-collector.newrelic.com/v1/newrelic_account_name/newrelic_account_id/events
Method: POST
Headers: {'X-insert-key': 'my_newrelic_key-XXXXXXXXXXX', 'Content-type': 'application/json'}
Payload: \[{'eventType': 'SubnetAlert', 'alertMessage': 'SubnetAlert'}\]
HTTP Error: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
Response Status Code: 404
Response Data: {}
```

I checked if my lambda function is able to make connection to internet by adding below block of code in my lambda function and it is returing output.
`

```
    try:         url = "https://www.example.com"         response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)         response_data = response.read().decode('utf-8')         print("HTTP request successful. Response:")         print(response_data)     except Exception as e:         print("Error:", e)        print(response_data)     except Exception as e:         print("Error:", e)
```

`
Output :

```
\`Received event: {"eventType": "SubnetAlert", "alertMessage": "Testing New Relic Integration"}
HTTP request successful. Response:
\<!doctype html\>

Example Domain

body {
background-color: #f0f0f2;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-family: -apple-system, system-ui, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
div {
width: 600px;
margin: 5em auto;
padding: 2em;
background-color: #fdfdff;
border-radius: 0.5em;
box-shadow: 2px 3px 7px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.02);
}
a:link, a:visited {
color: #38488f;
text-decoration: none;
}
@media (max-width: 700px) {
div {
margin: 0 auto;
width: auto;
}
}

<h1>Example Domain</h1>
<p>This domain is for use in illustrative examples in documents. You may use this
domain in literature without prior coordination or asking for permission.</p>
<p><a href="https://www.iana.org/domains/example">More information...</a></p>
```

Comment: The 404 means it's not a network issue, it's a response by newrelic. Did you replace the placeholders `newrelic_account_name` and `newrelic_account_id` in the url `https://insights-collector.newrelic.com/v1/newrelic_account_name/newrelic_account_id/events`?

Comment: yes, I removed the details while posting for security reasons.

Comment: Could anyone please help me out here?